# Parallelism in functional languages

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, functional-programming, lang

One of FP features advertised is that a program is "parallel by default" and that naturally fits modern multi-core processors. Indeed, reducing a tree is parallel by its nature. However, I don't understand how it maps to multi-threading. Consider the following fragment (pseudo code):

```
let y = read-and-parse-a-number-from-console
let x = get-integer-from-web-service-call
let r = 5 * x - y * 4
write-r-to-file
```

How can a translator determine which of tree branches should be run on a thread? After you obtained `x` or `y` it would be stupid to reduce `5 * x` or `y * 4` expressions on a separate thread (even if we grab it from a thread pool), wouldn't it? So how different functional languages handle this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We're not quite there yet.

Programs in pure declarative style (functional style is included in this category, but so are some other styles) tend to be much more amenable to parallelisation, because all data dependencies are explicit. This makes it very easy for the programmer to manually use primitives the language provides for specifying that two independent computations should be done in parallel, regardless of whether they share access to any data; if everything's immutable and there are no side effects, then changing the order in which things are done can't affect the result.

If purity is *enforced* by the language (as in Haskell, Mercury, etc, but unlike in Scala, F#, etc where purity is encouraged but unenforced), then it is *possible* for the compiler to attempt to automatically parallelise the program, but no existing language that I know of does this by default. If the language allows unchecked impure operations then it's generally impossible for the compiler to do the analysis necessary to prove that a given attempt to auto-parallelise the program is valid. So I do not expect any such language to ever support auto-parallelisation very effectively.

Note that the pseudo program you wrote is probably **not** pure declarative code. `let y = read-and-parse-a-number-from-console` and `let x = get-integer-from-web-service-call` are calculating `x` and `y` from impure external operations, and there's nothing in the program that fixes the order in which they should run. It's possible in general that executing two impure operations in either order will produce different results, and running those two operations in different threads gives up control of the order in which they run. So if a language like that was to auto-parallelise your program, it would almost certainly either introduce horrible concurrency bugs, or refuse to significantly parallelise anything.

However the functional style still makes it easy to manually parallelise such programs. A human programmer can tell that it almost certainly doesn't matter in which order you read from the console and the network. Knowing that there's no shared mutable state can decide to run those two operations in parallel without digging into their implementations (which you'd have to do in imperative algorithms where there might be mutable shared state even if it doesn't look like there is from the interface).

But the big complication that's in the way of auto-parallelising compilers for enforced-purity languages is knowing how *much* parallelisation to do. Running every computation possible in parallel vastly overwhelms any possible benefit with all the startup cost of spawning new threads (not to mention the context switches), as you try to run huge numbers of very short-lived threads on a small number of processors. The compiler needs to identify a much smaller number of "chunks" of computation that are reasonably large, and run the chunks in parallel while running the sub-computations of each chunk sequentially.

But only "embarrassingly parallel" programs decompose nicely into very large completely independent computations. Most programs are much more interdependent. So unless you only want to be able to auto-parallelise programs that are very easy to manually parallelise, your auto-parallelisation probably needs to be able to identify and run "chunks" in parallel which are partially dependent on each other, having them wait when they get to points that really need a result that's supposed to be computed by another "chunk". This introduces extra overhead of synchronisation between the threads, so the logic that chooses what to run in parallel needs to be even better in order to beat the trivial strategy of just running everything sequentially.

The developers of Mercury (a pure logical programming language) are working on various methods of tackling these problem, from static analysis to using profiling data. If you're interested, their [research papers](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/information/papers.html) have a lot more information. I presume other researches are working on this area in other languages, but I don't know much about any other projects.

Comment: Data Parallel Haskell is an interesting avenue of research: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell

Comment: This answer needs an update. There are now several auto-parallelizing compilers for functional programming languages such as [Futhark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56266733/975097).

Comment: @AndersonGreen I would welcome edits adding such information!

Answer (score 2):

In that *specific* example, the third statement depends on the first and the second, but there is no interdependency between the first and the second. Therefore, a runtime environment could execute `read-and-parse-a-number-from-console` on a different thread from `get-integer-from-web-service-call`, but the execution of the third statement would have to wait until the first two are finished.

Some languages or runtime environments may be able to calculate a partial result (such as `y * 4`) before obtaining an actual value of `x`. As a high level programmer though, you would be unlikely to be able to detect this.

Comment: OK, but what if i split the third statement into 3 atomic ones?

Comment: The compiler probably already does that for you. Without reference to a *specific* language and compiler, it's impossible to state in general what might happen.