# Could the "reduce" function be parallelized in Functional Programming?

Tags: parallel-processing, functional-programming, simd

In *Functional Programming*, one benefit of the `map` function is that it could be implemented to be executed in **parallel**.

So on a 4 cores hardware, this code and a parallel implementation of `map` would allow the 4 values to be **processed at the same time**.

```
let numbers = [0,1,2,3]
let increasedNumbers = numbers.map { $0 + 1 }
```

Fine, now lets talk about the `reduce` function.

> Return the result of repeatedly calling combine with an accumulated
>   value initialized to initial and each element of self, in turn, i.e.
>   return combine(combine(...combine(combine(initial, self[0]),
>   self[1]),...self[count-2]), self[count-1]).

My question: could the `reduce` function be implemented so to be executed in parallel?
Or, by definition, it is something that can **only be executed sequentially**?

Example:

```
let sum = numbers.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

Comment: the depends on the operation ... if you have a associative one then yes you can do `(a % b) % (c % d)` instead of `((a%b)%c)%d` for example (and do the inner ones in parallel before the outer one (if `%` is the operation)

Comment: sometimes you can break down the operation itself - a good example is sorting where you can do something like mergesort (which can be parallel) instead of insert sort ;)

Comment: You can consider `map` to be a special case of `reduce`. Now what does that mean for your question? :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Hi Bergi, I have difficulties considering `map` a special case of `reduce` because `map` does process each element of the array independently by the others. Infact the closure in the `map` receives only the `i-th` element of the array. So here I see no problems with parallelization. On the other hand the closure in the `reduce`, when applied to the i-th does need the result of the `reduce` applied to the `(i-1)-th` element (which can be problem for parallelization) + the current element.

Comment: @appzYourLife: What language are you using? `map f xss = reduce (x xs => cons (f x) xs) xss`.

Comment: @Bergi: I use Swift, however now I am more interested in a theoretical answer.

Comment: @appzYourLife: So you're working on arrays, not on lists? And with eager evaluation? In theory, `reduce` can produce a result whose parts can be evaluated in parallel. How that is implemented in practice, and in what ways it is equivalent to the parallel evaluation of the `map` call that you have in mind, is a different story.

Comment: @Bergi: Ok I see, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most common reductions is the sum of all elements.

```
((a+b) + c) + d == (a + b) + (c+d)  # associative
a+b == b+a                          # commutative
```

That equality works for integers, so you can change the order of operations from one long dependency chain to multiple shorter dependency chains, allowing multithreading and SIMD parallelism.

It's also true for mathematical real numbers, [**but not for floating point numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  In many cases, [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) is not expected, so the final result will be close enough to be worth the massive performance gain.  For C/C++ compilers, this is one of the optimizations enabled by the `-ffast-math` option.  (There's a `-fassociative-math` option for just this part of `-ffast-math`, without the assumptions about lack of infinities and NaNs.)

It's hard to get much SIMD speedup if one wide load can't scoop up multiple useful values.  Intel's AVX2 added "gathered" loads, but the overhead is very high.  With Haswell, it's typically faster to just use scalar code, but later microarchitectures do have faster gathers.  So SIMD reduction is **much more effective on arrays**, or other data that is stored contiguously.

Modern SIMD hardware works by loading 2 **consecutive** double-precision floats into a vector register (for example, with 16B vectors like [x86](/questions/tagged/x86)'s [sse](/questions/tagged/sse)).  There is a packed-FP-add instruction that adds the corresponding elements of two vectors.  So-called "vertical" vector operations (where the same operation happens between corresponding elements in two vectors) are much cheaper than "horizontal" operations (adding the two `double`s in one vector to each other).

---

So at the asm level, you have a loop that sums all the even-numbered elements into one half of a vector accumulator, and all the odd-numbered elements into the other half.  Then one horizontal operation at the end combines them.  So even without multithreading, using SIMD requires associative operations (or at least, close enough to associative, like floating point usually is).  If there's an approximate pattern in your input, like +1.001, -0.999, the cancellation errors from adding one big positive to one big negative number could be much worse than if each cancellation had happened separately.

With wider vectors, or narrower elements, a vector accumulator will hold more elements, increasing the benefit of SIMD.

Modern hardware has pipelined execution units that can sustain one (or sometimes two) FP vector-adds per clock, but the result of each one isn't ready for 5 cycles.  Saturating the hardware's throughput capabilities requires using multiple accumulators in the loop, so there are 5 or 10 separate loop-carried dependency chains.  (To be concrete, Intel Skylake does vector-FP multiply, add, or FMA (fused multiply-add) with 4c latency and one per 0.5c throughput.  4c/0.5c = 8 FP additions in flight at once to saturate Skylake's FP math unit.  Each operation can be a 32B vector of eight single-precision floats, four double-precision floats, a 16B vector, or a scalar.  (Keeping multiple operations in flight can speed up scalar stuff, too, but if there's any data-level parallelism available, you can probably vectorize it as well as use multiple accumulators.)  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for x86 instruction timings, pipeline descriptions, and asm optimization stuff.  But note that **everything here applies to ARM with NEON, PPC Altivec, and other SIMD architectures**.  They all have vector registers and similar vector instructions.

For a concrete example, [here's how gcc 5.3 auto-vectorizes a FP sum reduction](http://goo.gl/BwDvJw).  It only uses a single accumulator, so it's missing out on a factor of 8 throughput for Skylake.  clang is a bit more clever, and [uses two accumulators, but not as many as the loop unroll factor](http://goo.gl/pQtyGK) to get 1/4 of Skylake's max throughput.  Note that if you take out `-ffast-math` from the compile options, the FP loop uses `addss` (add scalar single) rather than `addps` (add packed single).  The integer loop still auto-vectorizes, because integer math is associative.

In practice, **memory bandwidth is the limiting factor most of the time.**  Haswell and later Intel CPUs can sustain two 32B loads per cycle from L1 cache.  [In theory, they could sustain that from L2 cache](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/532346).  The shared L3 cache is another story: it's a lot faster than main memory, but its bandwidth is shared by all cores.  This makes cache-blocking (aka [loop tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling)) for L1 or L2 a very important optimization when it can be done cheaply, when working with more than 256k of data.  Rather than producing and then reducing 10MiB of data, produce in 128k chunks and reduce them while they're still in L2 cache instead of the producer having to push them to main memory and the reducer having to bring them back in.  When working in a higher level language, your best bet may be to hope that the implementation does this for you.  This is what you ideally want to happen in terms of what the CPU actually does, though.

Note that all the SIMD speedup stuff applies within a single thread operating on a contiguous chunk of memory.  **You (or the compiler for your functional language!) can and should use both techniques, to have multiple threads each saturating the execution units on the core they're running on.**

---

Sorry for the lack of functional-programming in this answer.  You may have guessed that I saw this question because of the SIMD tag.  :P

I'm not going to try to generalize from addition to other operations.  IDK what kind of stuff you functional-programming guys get up to with reductions, but addition or compare (find min/max, count matches) are the ones that get used as SIMD-optimization examples.

Comment: Many thanks for your great answer. This stuff is extremely interesting.

Comment: @appzYourLife: cheers. :)  I wasn't even sure this kind of answer was what you were hoping for.

Comment: Thank you for the update and for the notification (indeed I did not notice the update). I'll read it very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There are some compilers for functional programming languages that parallelize the `reduce` and `map` functions. This is an example from the [Futhark](https://futhark-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language.html) programming language, which compiles into parallel CUDA and OpenCL source code:

```
let main (x: []i32) (y: []i32): i32 =
  reduce (+) 0 (map2 (*) x y)
```

It may be possible to write a compiler that would translate a subset of Haskell into Futhark, though this hasn't been done yet. The Futhark language does not allow recursive functions, but they may be implemented in a future version of the language.