# Arrays of Int arrays. Storing duplicates in order only

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm

I need to store an array of Int array for ordered duplicates (which are in a Array).

Example:

- Given array:
  `mainArray = [7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 5, 5]`

Now i need to create a 2D array of int Array.
Example:

```
Array [][] = [
               [7, 7], 
               [3], 
               [2, 2, 2], 
               [1], 
               [7],
               [5, 5]
             ]
```

Here is what I have:

```
for var i = 0; i < val.count; i++ {
    var columnArray = Array<Int>()
    for var j in 0...9 {
        if oldNum == val[j]{
            columnArray.append(val[j])
        }
        else {
            array.append(columnArray);
            //j += 1
            break;
        }
        oldNum = val[j];
        j += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how the question is asked. Little text and straight to the point.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't want an array of uniques as most answers (me included) are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method.

```
let result = numbers.reduce([[Int]]()) { (var result, num) -> [[Int]] in
    if var lastSequence = result.last where lastSequence.first == num {
        result[result.count-1].append(num)
    } else {
        result.append([num])
    }
    return result
}
```

### How does the reduce work?

`reduce` does apply the logic in the closure to an empty 2D array of integers (`[[Int]]`) and the first elm of `numbers`.

Then it is applied again to the result of the previous iteration and the second array of integers... and so on.

### What does happen in the closure?

The `if` does check whether the number in the last array added to the result is equals to the integer currently examined. If so that integer is added to that array.

Otherwise a new array containing only the new integer is added to the result.

### Test

```
[[7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [7], [5, 5]]
```

Comment: Heh @appzYourLife, seems you love reduce :) Like I last said, creating arrays / dictionary will decrease the performance greatly. (anyway I wanted to ask the link of your question about reduce the last time :).

Comment: @Eendje: ahah :D I really like Functional Programming indeed! This is the question about the [reduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247080/could-the-reduce-function-be-parallelized-in-functional-programming)

Comment: A very interesting read! Also you might want to read the link I've posted in my answer about creating arrays / dictionaries with reduce :p

Comment: Seems like this is the only answer that gives the result OP wants. +1 from me. The others made the same mistake I did. Gotta find a way to make it a one liner! :)

Comment: @Eendje: yes a one liner would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach extending collections where elements are equatable

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    var grouped: [[Element]] {
        var result: [[Element]] = []
        for element in self {
            if element == result.last?.last {
                result[result.index(before: result.endIndex)].append(element)
            } else {
                result.append([element])
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = [7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 5, 5]

array.grouped  // [[7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [7], [5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a programming logic problem problem. Your current code is totally wrong.

Here's one way you could solve it:

Start out by sorting your starting array. call that inputArray.

Create new, empty output "outerArray" and "innerArray" variables. Then loop through the entries in inputArray, testing for changes in value. If the value is the same as the last value, add that value to "innerArray". If the value has changed, save the previous innerArray to the outerArray and create a new, empty array and save it to innerArray.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give you what you need...

```
let mainArray = [7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 5, 5]
var newArray: [[Int]] = []

for var i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++ {
    let element = mainArray[i]
    if mainArray.indexOf(element) == i {
      var subArray = mainArray.filter({ $0 == element })
      newArray.append(subArray)
    }
}

print(newArray) // -> [[7, 7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `forEach` and keep the value of the last element to keep adding to your array while it's not different like in this way:

```
let mainArray = [7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 5, 5]

func filterTo2DArray(list: [Int] ) -> [[Int]] {

   var resultList = [[Int]]()

   list.forEach { x -> () in
      if let lastValue = resultList.last?.last where lastValue == x {
          resultList[resultList.count - 1].append(x)
      }
      else{
         resultList.append([x])
      }
   }
   return resultList
}


let t = filterTo2DArray(mainArray) //[[7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [7], [5, 5]]
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Only adjacent values with the same value should be grouped. Given the provided test input, the output should be `[[7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [7], [5, 5]]` as indicated in the OP.

Comment: Uhmm @appzYourLife Yes you're right my mistake I misunderstood the question I fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most boring iterative answer I can imagine. On the other hand it's easy to understand and doesn't suffer from potential complexity problems like `reduce` based solutions allegedly do:

```
var result: [[Int]] = []
var inner: [Int] = []

for i in mainArray {
  if i == inner.last {
    inner.append(i)
  } else {
    result.append(inner)
    inner = [i]
  }
}
result.append(inner)
// result == [[7, 7], [3], [2, 2, 2], [1], [7], [5, 5]]
```